# Qual o significado de & nesta sentenca em PHP?

Tags: php

Sentenca:

```
foreach ($this->table as $alias => &$tableObject) {
    $tableObject = clone $tableObject;
}
```

Qual o significado do **&** antes da variavel **$tableObject**?
Tenho visto alguns codigos que tem o & antes de alguma var somente um caracter e nao 2 como AND(&&) sempre antes de alguma variavel? Alguem pode me explicar, ou pelo menos me dizer o nome para eu poder pesquisar melhor.

Obrigado.

Comment: onde esta a pergunta duplicada? bfavaretto

Comment: No link ali de cima, no topo da sua pergunta. As respostas que tem lá não esclareceram sua dúvida? OBS: por favor mencione meu nome com @ na frente, senão não serei notificado.

Comment: ok, ja achei, obrigado pela orientacao.

Comment: Se aqueles conteúdos não resolverem, me explique aqui qual é a dúvida que eu ajudo.

Comment: Obrigado, mas esta bem explicado e ainda tem outros links de referencia nas respostas. Vlw.